# EmEditorの「ファイルから検索」で長いパスのファイルがエラーになる

Tags: emeditor

EmEditorの「ファイルから検索」を使って検索したとき、検索範囲に長いパス（260文字くらい？）のファイルがあると、検索結果に以下のようなエラーが出力されます。

```
C:\.....(長いファイルパス).....: *** オープンに失敗しました。 ***
```

これを防ぐ方法はありませんか？

Windows10 Pro
EmEditor 20.5.2

なお、[この記事の「方法1: グループポリシーで設定する」](https://itojisan.xyz/trouble/20895/#1-2)は試しましたが、効果はありませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

長いパスへの対応は、v20.6 の新機能となります。最新版の v20.5.911 以上でお試しください。

Comment: 20.5.912にアップデートしてみましたが、変わりませんでした。

Comment: 問題が再現できるサンプル ファイルを zip に圧縮し、再現する手順を書いて、 tech @ emurasoft.com 宛にお送りください。

Comment: メール送りました

Comment: メール受け取りました。20.5.913 でお試しください。

Comment: 非常に素早い対応、ありがとうございます！　無事解決しました